# Android Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch

Tags: java, android, gradle

My project is multidex, but i faced this error for first run and it dissapears for second run.

```
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.String[] using a local variable of type android.os.Bundle. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.io.InputStream using a local variable of type java.lang.String[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.io.InputStream using a local variable of type java.lang.String[]. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type boolean. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.
4 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForCbuConfDevDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My gradle looks like below. I already did multidex development.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 33
    versionName "2.3"

    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
}
```

Comment: did you set `multiDexEnabled true`? call `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` Then clean-rebuild

Comment: did you add multidex support to your application instance

Comment: Yes "multiDexEnabled true" setted under defaultConfig @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Yes i did it @EpicPandaForce

Comment: There is more to your error message that you are not showing. I'm not sure why you think multidex will fix it

Comment: I added all errors @cricket_007 I think because, I faced this problem after multidex developmet.

Comment: Uncaught translation error isn't going to be fixed by multidex, though. Multidex only fixes having more than 65k methods defined in your app

Comment: How can ı solve Uncaught translation error? @cricket_007

Comment: From what I researched, it seems to be caused by some mismatched files at the compile/build step. If a clean/rebuild doesn't fix it, then disabling instant run, or messing with progaurd have been possible solutions, but I can't find a definite answer, sorry. You could try actually removing multidex until you get the error message that says you need it.

Comment: Similar issue here. This solution worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45026077/5073372

Comment: Hi, i can not resolve this issue still. A third part lib caused it and i had to remove the lib :/